# Bootstrap Horizontal and Veritcal scroll with fixed footer and header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, sass

I am working on table where I am trying to achieve vertical and horizontal scroll but didn't find any solution . Could someone please help me how to achieve this issue . Any example or code snippet will be appreciate

Thanks

Comment: Please share some code example to easily understand what you want.

Comment: Can you please add the code you've attempted so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this what you need, but you can wrap the table in wrapper element and set `overflow: scroll` to the wrapper.

```css
    .wrapper {
        height: 200px;
        position: relative;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }


    table td {
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    table thead th {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        background: #fff;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }

    table tfoot td {
        background: #fff;
        border: none;
        position: sticky;
        bottom: 0;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

          <table>
            
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>head</th>
              <th>head</th>
              <th>head</th>
              <th>head</th>
              <th>head</th>
              <th>head</th>
              <th>head</th>
              <th>head</th>
              <th>head</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
          
            <tr>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
              <td>Data</td>
            </tr>
            
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td>foot</td>
              <td>foot</td>
              <td>foot</td>
              <td>foot</td>
              <td>foot</td>
              <td>foot</td>
              <td>foot</td>
              <td>foot</td>
              <td>foot</td>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>

        </div>
```

**Edit 1:** added `thead` & `tfoot` and made them fixed.

**Edit 2:** added padding to `thead` & `tfoot`.

**Edit 3:** made the table to scroll only vertically.

Comment: Need to fixed it header

Comment: Like thead and tfooter . Could you please help me

Comment: I have edited the code. I have added `thead` & `tfoot` and applied `position: sticky` to them.

Comment: Thank you for answer , can I have some space between `thead` and main body , same as `tfoot` and main body

Comment: you can add `padding` to thead th and tfoot td if you need spacing.

Comment: Could you please update your answer ?

Comment: also, I need to just enable scroll in body

Comment: please check this link https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/react/tables/scroll/ . I need same like this .

Comment: means , I don't want to scroll header and footer

Comment: *I don't want to scroll header and footer* change the `overflow` property to `overflow-y` and omit width.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218903/discussion-between-jonas-and-debsmita-paul).